# Selected text in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, selection

In this exercise, I have been given the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Selected text</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container_inside">
    <h1>Pseudo-elements</h1>
    <p class="my_paragraph">The Almighty CSS allows you to not only work with
      elements declared in your HTML code but to also customize those parts of
      the page you can not address using simple selectors. This might be the
      customization of the first line of the paragraph, the first letter of the
      paragraph, or even the part of the text user has just selected.</p>
    <p>Here is the list of the most-used pseudo-elements:</p>
    <ul class="my_list">
      <li>::first-line</li>
      <li>::first-letter</li>
      <li>::placeholder</li>
      <li>::marker</li>
      <li>::before</li>
      <li>::after</li>
      <li>::selection</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The task is to 'Make the text inside .my_paragraph have white color and black background when it is selected.'

Here is the CSS code that is given:

```
/* Write your code here */


.my_paragraph::first-line {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #9d3ce9, #5fbf85);
    color: white;
}

.my_list li::marker {
    color: #9d3ce9;
}

.container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
}

.container_inside {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 80%;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
}

.my_list {
    text-align: left;
}
```

So I added this bit to the CSS section:

```
.my_paragraph::selection {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

What am I missing? Why is this wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add this for selection

```
 .my_paragraph::selection {
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
    }
 .my_paragraph::-moz-selection { color: white;
        background-color: black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adding your style to your html file!
Add this to your html header and replace style.css by your css file name:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, correct code has been found:

```
.my_paragraph::selection {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
```